# Pin 100k hashes on own IPFS cluster

Tags: ipfs, ipfs-cli

I am running an IPFS cluster in the cloud and I would like to pin about 100k hashes of objects from the network.

I'm currently iterating through the list using the `ipfs pin add <hash>`, but it's taking forever (as some hashes can't be found immediately or take long time to be found)

Is there a way to request a IPFS node/cluster to `pin add` hashes in batches? A best effort approach would suffice as I know some hashes may have disappeared or not be reacheable anymore.

Is there a way to achieve this quickly?

Comment: https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/cli/#ipfs-pin-add - writes "Path to object(s) to be pinned.", can't you put several hashes as parameters, or is that still too slow?

Answer (score 2):

You can stream a list of files to `ipfs pin add` on STDIN. Here, `/path/to/hashes` is a file with one IPFS hash on each line:

```sh
ipfs pin add < /path/to/hashes
```

You can also pass the `--progress` flag to see the current pinning progress.

Comment: Thanks, this is really an elegant and neat way, do you know if there is a timeout of some sorts? Say one of the hashes can't be found, will it get stuck there forever?